# Delete all images in multiple directories older than 1 day

Tags: php

I've successfully used this script to delete all images older than a day in a single specified directory.

However I have several image folders that need this treatment. While I could just duplicate the deletion script, I'd rather try to keep in one script.

All the image folders are subfolders of the main folder, so ideally I'd recursively look for all images older than a day in all subfolders of the specified path.

```
<?php 
$days = 1;
$path = '/home/boston64/public_html/webcams/';
$filetypes_to_delete = array("jpg");

// Open the directory
if ($handle = opendir($path))
{
    // Loop through the directory
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        // Check the file we're doing is actually a file
        if (is_file($path.$file))
        {
            $file_info = pathinfo($path.$file);
            if (isset($file_info['extension']) && in_array(strtolower($file_info['extension']), $filetypes_to_delete))
            {
                // Check if the file is older than X days old
                if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )
                {
                    // Do the deletion
                    unlink($path.$file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the following work? I accept no responsibility yada yada etc, so I'd recommend that you backup the folder before testing ;)

```
<?php 

function deleteOldImages($days, $path, $filetypes_to_delete) {
    // Open the directory
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        // Loop through the directory
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            // Check the file we're doing is actually a file
            if (is_file($path.$file)) {
                $file_info = pathinfo($path.$file);
                if (isset($file_info['extension']) && in_array(strtolower($file_info['extension']), $filetypes_to_delete)) {
                    // Check if the file is older than X days old
                    if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) ) {
                        // Do the deletion
                        unlink($path.$file);
                    }
                }
            } else if (is_dir($path.$file)) {
                deleteOldImages($days, $path.$file, $filetypes_to_delete);
            }
        }
    }
}

deleteOldImages(1, '/home/boston64/public_html/webcams/', array("jpg"));

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try - for my own education: I'm having trouble following it, which code segment deals with recursively checking subfolders?

Comment: It's untested, so yep, emphasis on "try"! So you can see that I've defined a function called `deleteOldImages(...)`. Inside that function, it loops over everything in the directory, and if the thing is a directory, the function calls itself (recursively) on that subdirectory. And obviously, for each thing in that subdirectory, if there are more directories, the function will call itself (recursively) on THAT sub subdirectory, and so on.

Comment: (split comment sorry) The recursion is started with the last line of code there that actually calls the function, and you can see that it will end when it has considered every element in the file system tree in a depth first manner.